# How to serve TFTP content via script (PHP-like)?

Tags: linux, php, bash, tftp

I am looking for a way to serve TFTP requests with an output from a script (bash, PHP?) called with the TFTP request path as an argument. A simple TFTP equivalent of Apache+PHP.

Something like PHP + mod_rewrite, ie. when client requests "file123", the server would call a script (eg. ".\myscript.sh file123") and pass the output of the script as the returned TFTP data.

Can anyone hint a good, production-worthy solution? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question that you are looking for hooks inside of a tftp server. Maybe something like this? https://github.com/tftp-go-team/hooktftp

Comment: Thanks for that one :)